# NotFoundError Node was not found image_div.parentNode.removeChild(img)

Tags: javascript, html

I am having problems getting removeChild() to work. I am getting "NotFoundError: Node was not found image_div.parentNode.removeChild(img);" error

Here is my code:

```
<div id="imagesframe"> </div>

<script>
images_array = [image1.jpg,image2.jpg,image3.jpg,image4.jpg,image5.jpg];
var image_div = document.getElementById('imagesframe');
for(var i=0 ; i<images_array.length ; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = images_array[i];
    img.style.width = '500px';
    img.style.height = '500px';
    setTimeout(function(){image_div.appendChild(img)},1000);
    image_div.parentNode.removeChild(img);
}
</script>
```

the last line:
    image_div.parentNode.removeChild(img);
is causing the problem.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Why you're trying to find the image from the parent of the parent? `img.parentNode.removeChild(img)` would be better. `img` can't be found before the timeout has expired, though. Maybe you've misunderstood the `setTimeout`, it doesn't delay the execution of the rest of the code, it delays just invoking the function passed in the argument.

Comment: I even tried image_div.removeChild(img); but that does NOT work. So what would work here? Okay now I see I have to fix my setTimeout () function, this is more complicated now. Looks like I am going to have to figure another solution.

Comment: Please explain what you're actually trying to do? Show one image for second and the show the next etc.?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to show one image after another where the first image disappears and the next image is displayed in the same location, for all images in the array in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `setTimeout` within a loop makes things complex when passing a correct `img` to the argument function. Also you probably have omitted quotes around image URLs in the array.

Then the `setTimeout`, it doesn't prevent the loop to be executed, it's just a timer, which launches the argument function after the given delay. In your code (without other errors) all five function calls would be done almost at the same time after one second, since the loop creates a new timer on each round within microseconds.

Here's an alternative approach using simple outer scope access.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var imagesArray = ['image1.jpg','image2.jpg','image3.jpg','image4.jpg','image5.jpg'], // URLs of the images
        imageDiv = document.getElementById('imagesframe'), // An element wherein to show the images
        counter = 0, // Image counter
        img;  // A temporary image element

    // Changes images in an element
    function changeImg (first) {
        if (!first) { // Check, if there's an image to remove
            imageDiv.removeChild(img); // Remove an image
        } else { // Reset counter, just in case the slideshow will be reused
            counter = 0;
        }
        // Create a new image and append it to an element
        img = new Image();
        img.src = imagesArray[counter];
        img.style.width = '500px';
        img.style.height = '500px';
        imageDiv.appendChild(img);
        // Show more images or quit
        counter += 1;
        if (counter < 5) { // Show the next image
            setTimeout(changeImg, 1000);
        } else { // Remove the last image
            setTimeout(function () {imageDiv.removeChild(img)}, 1000);
        }
    }
    changeImg(true); // Show the first image
    return;
};
```

The code is placed to the `head` and wrapped within `window.onload`. If needed, you can wrap it within an IIFE, and place it on it's original position in your code. A wrapper is needed to avoid declaring global variables.

IIFE = Immediately Invoked Function Expression, and it looks somewhat like this:

```
(function () {/* Code to run here */}());
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this very detailed code answer! It is not as simple as I originally thought! Recursion definitely makes sense here.

Comment: Actually the code is not recursive, it is re-called from outside of it. Anyway, this type of implementation is widely used with timeouts. You can do this with a loop also, but it would be more complex than my simple approach. If you feel the answer was useful, you could accept it by ticking a checkmark on the top-left corner of the answer. By accepting an answer, other visitors can see, that your problem is solved, and we both will earn some rep

Comment: Not recursive? From line

    if (counter < 5) { // Show the next image
            setTimeout(changeImg, 1000);    it is recursive because it is being called from inside the function.
 I am trying to vote you up but it won't let me. Apparently I need more reputation to do so which I think is stupid.

Comment: `changeImg` is _not called inside_ of `changeImg`, and the execution is not returned back to `changeImg` as well, hence the code is not recursive. Timed `changeImage`s are called by browser in a quite similar process to event listening (unless even the same), and the execution is returned to that process too. About voting, you'll need 15 rep to get Vote up privileg. It's quickly earned, you can start by accepting the answer, if you feel it has solved your problem ; ).

Comment: I accepted your answer :-) I guess I am getting confused by what you mean that is not recursive. Cause seeing a function call within itself is what I see from your code answer.

Comment: The point is, that the function doesn't call itself, it calls `setTimeout` only, and the process `setTimeout` runs, calls the function. You can loop the timeouts outside of the function, and get technically the same result. The difference is, that you have more control over the execution, when you set the timers within a function.